# Problemas con atom

Tags: atom-editor

desde el sábado que tengo problemas con ATOM,me mostraba de una actualización disponible - y me apareció una figura de una ardilla en la parte inferior derecha, el cual hice click y desde ahí no funcionó - desinstalé, volví a instalar una versión anterior PERO no hubo caso (me aparece así como está en la foto) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que esto te podría guiar <https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-restart-atom/36049>

Answer (score -1):

Buen día, estuve buscando por internet el problema que presentaba con *ATOM* - consulté en el foro del mismo editor - y lo pude solucionar con el siguiente comentario: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/14509#issuecomment-314671037

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]